# query to get all message of all sender's of a login user who's id is 7

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql database. 
I want to display all conversion of login user.
this is my table structure in mysql.

```html
<table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          id
          </td>
        <td>
          senderuserid
          </td>
        <td>
          receiveruserid
          </td>
        <td>
          message
          </td>
        <td>
          time
          </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE senderuserid = 7 OR receiveruserid = 7
```